# Выходит ошибка TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Все сделал как надо. Но почемуто спрашивает location, я не знаю в чем проблема. За ранее спасибо

Вот мой код :

```
import './App.css';
import About from './Components/jsx/About';
import Content from './Components/jsx/Content';
import Header from './Components/jsx/Header';
import Navbar from './Components/jsx/Navbar';
import { BrowserRouter, Router, Switch  } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter >
    <Switch>
          <div className="wrapper">
            <Header/>
            <Navbar/>
      <Router exact  path="/" component={About}/>
      <Router exact  path="/Content" component={Content}/>
          </div>
      </Switch>    
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
export default App;

Package.json:
 "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.5",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.7.1",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-router": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.2",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.0"
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Опечатка: `Router` должен быть `Route` :

```
import './App.css';
import About from './Components/jsx/About';
import Content from './Components/jsx/Content';
import Header from './Components/jsx/Header';
import Navbar from './Components/jsx/Navbar';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch  } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter >
    <Switch>
      <div className="wrapper">
        <Header/>
        <Navbar/>
        <Route exact  path="/" component={About}/>
        <Route exact  path="/Content" component={Content}/>
      </div>
     </Switch>    
   </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
export default App;
```